# Histogram equalization

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I seems to be stuck in one of my derivation regarding histogram equalization. The other StackExchange answers didn't help me go through it. I would like someone to check if my derivation/set up is correct as well as help me finish.

So the problem is that we have an image with intensities values in $[0,1]$. We set the probability density function of the image as $p:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We set the distribution function as $P:\sigma([0,1]) \rightarrow [0,1]$. We also set a transition function from old intensity to new ones as $g:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$. Now from probability theory we have :
\begin{align}
P(x < a) = \int_0^a p(t)dt = F(a)
\end{align}
With $F$ being the cumulative distribution function. Now let's assume $y = g(x)$ where y is the transformed intensity and assume g is monotone increasing. We have :
\begin{align}
F_2(a) = P(y < a) = P(g(x) < a) = P(x < g^{-1}(a)) = F(g^{-1}(a))
\end{align}
Where $F_2$ is the cumulative distribution function of the transformed intensities. Now let's take derivatives :
\begin{align}
F_2'(a) &= F(g^{-1}(a))' \\
&= F'(g^{-1}(a)).(g^{-1})'(a)\\ 
&= p(g^{-1}(a)).(g^{-1})'(a)
\end{align}

We want the density of the transformed pixel to be constant so $F_2'(a) = (\int_0^a dt)' = 1$ So that :
\begin{align}
1 = p(g^{-1}(a)).(g^{-1})'(a)
\end{align}

Now in all solutions I've found they say to take $g^{-1}(a) = \int_0^a p(t)dt$. But when plugging in to see if everything checks out I'm left with:
\begin{align}
1 = p\big( \int_0^a p(t)dt\big).p(a)
\end{align}

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem seems to come from my sloppy notation. The probability function $P$ can't be used to model both histogram. To be able to do that I need to be more precise and use random variable. Here is the solution I came out with :

- Let $\Omega = [0,N-1]$ be the probability space equipped with the usual sigma algebra. $N$ is the number of pixels in the image.
- Let X and Y be Random variable such that $X:\Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$ and $Y:\Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$. X and Y  represent the assignment of a pixels intensity (continuous case ). X is going to model the current image, and Y is going to represent the image with the flat histogram.
- Let $g:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ represent the mapping function from old intensities to new ones.
  With these definitions we have $Y(\omega) = g(X(\omega))$. Now let's calculate the cumulative distribution function of Y :

\begin{align}
P_Y(y<b) &= PY^{-1}(y<b) \\
&= P(\{\omega \in \Omega | Y(\omega) < b\})\\
&= P(\{\omega \in \Omega | g(X(\omega)) < b\})\\
&=P(\{\omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) < g^{-1}(b)\}) \text{ g is monotone increasing}\\
&= PX^{-1}(y<g^{-1}(b)) \\
&=\int_0^{g^{-1}(b)} f(t)dt
\end{align}

On the other hand since Y has a flat density we have $P_Y(y<b) = b$ so that :
\begin{align}
b &= \int_0^{g^{-1}(b)} f(t)dt\\
g(b) &= \int_0^{b} f(t)dt\\
\end{align}

Does that sounds right ?